# Parse args passed from aws System Manager send_command

Tags: aws-ssm

I have a long running job that cannot finish within lambda 15 minutes limit. So, I decided to use an EC2 worker instance to run the job. The job needs to be kicked off from a lambda function. I am using the following Python code to send the command to EC2 instance.

```
ssm.send_command(
    InstanceIds=['*****'],
    DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
    Parameters={'commands': [f'/home/ssm-user/get_cert_attributes.sh --doc_id={doc_id}']})
```

Shell script is getting called. However, I am unable to parse the args --doc_id. I am using the below code block to parse the arg. doc_id is coming blank. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "${1:-}" != "" ]; do
    case "$1" in
        "-d" | "--doc_id")
        shift
        doc_id=$1
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
echo $doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by creating my own ssm document:

```
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Get document attributes"
parameters:
  docid:
    type: "String"
    description: "Document id to be processed"
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runShellScript"
  name: "GetDocAttr"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
    - "/home/ssm-user/get_cert_attributes.sh --doc_id {{docid}}"
```

On the shell script side, I had to use export doc_id to export the environment variable to use it in subsequent child sessions.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "${1:-}" != "" ]; do
    case "$1" in
        "-d" | "--doc_id")
        shift
        doc_id=$1
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
echo $doc_id
export doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to run a shell script with arguments like this. You don't need all the messaging and other information, but it's there just in case.

```
commands = ['sudo -u ec2-user ./p1_consolidate.sh 0 1 0']
instanceid = 'i-0780a999exxxdxxx'
ssmc = boto3.client('ssm')
response_send = ssmc.send_command(
    DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
    Parameters={'commands': commands,
                'workingDirectory': ['/home/ec2-user'],
                'executionTimeout': ['14400']},
    OutputS3BucketName='xxxxx-data-files-for-functions',
    OutputS3KeyPrefix='ssm-outputfiles-automation/',
    InstanceIds=[instanceid],
    ServiceRoleArn='arn:aws:iam::xxxxx6657583:role/SNS-Publish-SSM-Statuses',
    NotificationConfig={
                        'NotificationArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxx6657583:your-sns',
                        'NotificationEvents': ['All'],
                        'NotificationType': 'Command'}
     

               )
```

p1_consolidate.sh stored in /home/ec2-user/ directory
Just takes the three arguments sent via commands below. Then the python file runs with those arguments.

```
s=$1
e=$2
q=$3

nohup python /home/ec2-user/code/mypythonfile.py -s $s -e $e -q $q &
```